# max with condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

search array: `[['#S!', 1, 1], ['#$@', 2, 5], ['#S!', 10, 12], ['#$@', 21, 5]]`

and key array: `['#S!','#$@']`

I want to look up into search array based on the key array element and create a resultant array which looks like this:

[[`key array element`,`max while lookup for value at index 1 in search array`, `max while lookup for value at index 2 in search array`], [...]]

Here is my code for the same:

```
let resultant = [];
  keys.forEach((ele, ind) => {
                 resultant[ind] = [
                                   ele,
                                   Math.max(searchArray.filter(element => element[0] === ele)),
                                   Math.max(searchArray.filter(element => element[0] === ele))
                             ];
                 });
```

Now I am confused in these statements:

```
Math.max(newSet.filter(element => element[0] === ele)),
Math.max(newSet.filter(element => element[0] === ele))
```

Because filter will return the entire array but I want to find max of element with index 1 and in second statement I want to return max of element with index 2 which have the element with index 0 same as the key which I have provided.

Here is one simple test case:

search Array: `[["A",1,2],["A",12,23],["A",11,23],["A",14,42],["A",71,32],["B",113,42],["B",145,62],["C",91,32],["C",14,222],["C",111,2]]`

keys Array: `["A","B","C"]`

Output: `[["A",71,42],["B",145,62],["C",111,222]]`

As you can see max corresponding to the elements are mapped to the same elements. Can someone help me with this? Is there a better or more optimized algorithm for the same than what I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach with an object for the wanted keys.

```js
function max(search, keys) {
    const temp = search.reduce((r, [key, ...data]) => {
        if (!r[key]) r[key] = [key, ...data];
        else data.forEach((v, i) => { if (r[key][i + 1] < v) r[key][i + 1] = v; });
        return r;
    }, {});

    return keys.map(key => temp[key]);
}

console.log(max([['#S!', 1, 1], ['#$@', 2, 5], ['#S!', 10, 12], ['#$@', 21, 5]], ['#S!','#$@']));
console.log(max([["A", 1, 2],["A", 12, 23],["A", 11, 23], ["A", 14, 42], ["A", 71, 32], ["B", 113, 42], ["B", 145, 62], ["C", 91, 32], ["C", 14, 222], ["C", 111, 2]], ["A", "B", "C"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use js array flatten method to do this,

```js
let searchArray = [["A",1,2],["A",12,23],["A",11,23],["A",14,42],["A",71,32],["B",113,42],["B",145,62],["C",91,32],["C",14,222],["C",111,2]];

let keysArray = ["A","B","C"];

console.clear();
let output = [];
keysArray.forEach(item => {
    let groupSearchArray = searchArray.filter(f => f[0] === item);
    let sortedArray = groupSearchArray.flat(1).filter(f => f !== item).sort().reverse();
    output.push([item, sortedArray[0], sortedArray[1]]); 
});

console.log(output);
```